# Is there a way to iterate through nested structs with a varying number of fields in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-struct

I am looking for a way to iterate through nested structs in MATLAB, with each sub-struct containing a varying number of fields, some of which may contain further nested structs. For example, I have the following struct A:

```
    A.a.alpha=[2,3];
    A.a.beta=[8,9,10];
    A.a.delta.k=[5,6,7];
    A.a.delta.m=1;
    A.b.alpha=[22,32];
    A.b.beta.n=3;
    A.b.beta.o=[0,140];
```

Is there any way that I can automatically iterate through each of the end nodes of the struct A such that I can access A.a.alpha, A.a.beta, A.a.delta.k, A.a.delta.m, A.b.alpha, A.b.beta.n, and A.b.beta.o?

So far, I have seen nested for loops being used to access information that is a specific depth in (so accessing A.a.alpha, A.a.beta, A.b.alpha, but not A.a.delta.k, A.a.delta.m, A.b.beta.n, or A.b.beta.o), but my struct has those variable depths at which I need information access. I did consider using a "check if a sub-struct exists" method, but I can't figure out how to appropriately use that information to accomplish my goal here. Likewise, I also considered using a while loop that would stop at some A.end field but can't wrap my head around how to actually dig deeper into the variable depth sub-structs.

Comment: I think you need a recursive function that goes "if input is struct -> get struct fields; iteratie trhough struct fields -> if struct fields is struct -> call self". With some else statement for when its not a struct, and tehrefore you can do whattever function you want.

Comment: I agree @Ander Biguri. That definitely seems like a feasible approach in principle and was also my first thought. It's the logistics of how I could do that automatically that escape me. I don't know how deep the deepest end node is, and even if I figured that out, I'm not sure how to set up an appropriately variable nested if statement or loop for executing that.

Comment: this is why you want recursivity. If every time you find a struct in a field, you just call the function itself, it will keep going regardless of the depth. The answer you have gotten uses recursivity.

Comment: Understood now. Thank you all for your prompt help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the field names (or the data directly) using a recursive function, which calls itself on substructures.

Then you can use `getfield()` to grab data out of nested structures, for example in your demo `getfield( A, 'a', 'alpha' )` would return `[2,3]`, but we can also do

```
fieldSplit = {'a','alpha'};
data = getfield( A, fieldSplit{:} );
```

So by using a recursive function to generate all of the nested field names, we can generate `fieldSplit` for each subfield of your structure and pull out data at arbitrary depths.

Full demo with commented code for more details:

```
% Demo data
A = struct();
A.a.alpha=[2,3];
A.a.beta=[8,9,10];
A.a.delta.k=[5,6,7];
A.a.delta.m=1;
A.b.alpha=[22,32];
A.b.beta.n=3;
A.b.beta.o=[0,140];

% Get the nested field names
f = getNestedFields( A );

% Extract any data you want, or all of it
data = cell(1, numel(f));
for ii = 1:numel(f)
    % Split the field name on the dot separators
    fieldSplit = strsplit( f{ii}, '.' ); 
    % Use getfield to get nested data
    data{ii} = getfield( A, fieldSplit{:} );
end


function fields = getNestedFields( strct )
    % Get the field names of this structure
    fields = fieldnames( strct );
    % Loop over the fields
    for ii = 1:numel(fields)        
        if isstruct( strct.(fields{ii}) )
            % This is a substructure, recursively fetch fields
            % Replace this field name with subfield list
            fields{ii} = strcat( fields{ii}, '.', getNestedFields(strct.(fields{ii})) );
        else
            % This is a non-struct field. Nest the name so that when we
            % "flatten" things in a few lines we get back to a cell
            fields{ii} = fields(ii);
        end
    end
    % Flatten the names out to get all fields in one denested cell array
    fields = [fields{:}];
end
```

Result:

[image: output]